# Do the User Id properties of email aliases remain the same in Google Apps / App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps, google-account

It's possible to have nicknames / aliases for your email accounts in Google Apps - so if I have email ID a1@domain.com with nicknames a2 and a3, will the [`user_id` property](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userclass.html#User_user_id) on App Engine differ when I use these different aliases to login?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't log in with an email alias unless you [create a Google account](https://www.google.com/accounts/NewAccount) for them, in which case they will appear as their own separate account, indistinguishable from any other.